# Отключить звук камеры програмно

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Подскажите, как можно отключить звук камеры на устройстве? Т.е в приложение делается фото и необходимо отключить звук "затвора" при съемке.
Вариант с переводом устройства в бесшумный режим, а потом в обычный не рассматриваю. В справке инфы толком не нашел.

Comment: отключить программно на телефоне или же твое приложение делает снимок со звуком и ты хочешь отключить этот звук именно внутри твоего приложения ?

Comment: @Senior Automator
в приложение

Comment: вы плохо искали просто. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476791/android-mute-camera-shutter-sound

Comment: @Senior Automator
я форум весь пересмотрел,везде предлагают отключать звук или переводить в вибро

Comment: посмотрите второй ответ, где предлагается отключить именно звук затвора `mCamera.enableShutterSound(false);`